# Get the function value while suppressing fprintf

Tags: matlab, function, plot, printing

Suppose that I have a function that looks like this:

```
function c=Add(a,b)
c=a+b;
fprintf('%f',c)
```

Now, I want the value Add(7,5) to be used in another command, says

```
y=sin(A(7,5))
```

but I don't want it to execute the command fprintf. More generally, I want to know the following.

> Is it possible to get only the end value of a function and suppressing the inner commands like *plot* or *fprintf* altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the output to the command window using [`evalc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html):

```
[~,val]= evalc('Add(7,5)');
y= sin(val);
```

Comment: Why did you write [~,val] when my function's only output is a number? Did I miss something?

Comment: @BigbearZzz The first output of `evalc` is the output  normally written to the command window during the evaluation of  its argument. The result of the evaluation is the second (third, etc) output.